# jQuery "jFlow" script and positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I am using the popular jFlow content slider on the Wordpress site I am developing. I have managed to get the look I want using css, but I cannot get the bannercontent div that shows a post's text about the thumbnail image to hide the post's not currently active. Sounds confusing, but if you look at http://www.thurstonenergy.org/wordpress/ you'll see what I mean. Anyone else use this script and have similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use overflow:hidden so that only one image at a time shows. Then you make the div around your images only the height/width of one image. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a z-index to the elements. Worked for me in Firebug:

```
.jFlow {
position:relative;
z-index:100;

.bannercontent {
position:absolute;
z-index:50;}
```

Hopefully that does the trick for you. As I mentioned, I tested it quickly and it appeared to do the trick.

Comment: I appreciate your help John, thank you. I tried adding z-indexes, but they were already positioned correctly at the top before I added them. The trouble is the .bannercontent... I keep seeing other slide info to the right, as the active one scrolls in. They are only supposed to show one at a time.

Comment: firebug wasn't showing a z-index for those elements, oddly. and when I added them it fixed the problem. bizarre. good luck!